# Can we have “duplicate symbols” error when using frameworks in pure swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

Years ago, using ObjC and frameworks (and frameworks inside frameworks), it was common from time to time the “duplicate symbols” error. For example, if you created a framework including RestKit and then the app that wanted to use that framework was using RestKit too, you had that error. One way to fix it was to rename the included source code into your framework using a prefix. Or just avoid using 3rd party dependencies on your framework. Note we used to use static libraries, rather than dynamic libraries.

Is it possible to have the same problem with pure swift apps/frameworks and dynamic libraries today? As far as I understand, swift uses the concept of module for namespaces, something we didn’t have with ObjC.

I mean, is it possible to create a framework that uses Alamofire (let’s say version 5), and then create an app that uses Alamofire (let’s say version 5.0.1) AND your framework that uses Alamofire too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a similar setup and i did not face any such duplicate symbols in my project.

Let me share my experience.

I have a project setup like the one below.

```
Main Project -> uses PromiseKit via Cocoapods
My Framework -> uses PromiseKit via Cocoapods
Main Project uses My Framework
```

I did not face any such issue while running this setup. IMO, hope it is taken care by Swift compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I guess that is because cocoapods compiles the code into your app (or framework), so, because they have different module names, there is no collision.
One question, can you have different versions of PromiseKit without problems?

Comment: @Ricardo Did you find an answer to your question? Can we link the same (static) framework with different versions?

Comment: @manmal If you have the same framework linked statically but 2 versions, the only solution I found was to change the one of the modules name. I recommend you rename the old one to AAAALegacy or similar, so every time you update the most recent version, there is no need to rename anything.

Comment: @Ricardo I see, thanks for that insight. In the meantime I've found that multiple different versions of the same Framework can be referenced by always using `@_implementationOnly import PromiseKit` instead of any `import PromiseKit`. At least that worked in my SPM + XCFrameworks spike. Not sure about Cocoapods.

Comment: @_implementationOnly is discussed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996

Comment: @manmal Amazing, I didn't know @_implementationOnly. Thanks a lot.